# What is the Vim command to quit all open windows?

Tags: vim

`:q` only closes the current window. If you are using tabs or split windows, you need to do `:q` for all of them. Also, plugins like **NERDTree** and **MiniBufExpl** have their own windows, which need to be closed individually.

Is there a command to quit all these open windows and quit Vim in a single stroke? However, if there is some buffer or window with unsaved changes, I should be asked to save it or not. Any command to achieve this?

I hope this is not a strange request, because this is how most non-Vim editors with tab or splits work.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can quit all loaded and open buffers, splits and tabs with:

```
:qa
```

If you want to quit without saving:

```
:qa!
```

You could assign a mapping to do this with a single stroke, this assigns the comma to quit everything without prompting to save:

```
nnoremap , :qa!<CR>
```

`:wqall` writes before closing, that might be useful.

Type `:he :qa` in vim for more info

Comment: I like the shortcut - although accidentally hitting comma in normal mode and *losing all your work* doesn't sound that great :P

Comment: @JasonCemra Just a tiny trap for mindless copy-pasters, I guess.

Answer (score 10):

you can user the

```
:qall
:qa
```

quit all the tabs opened

then you can use the command

```
:tabo
```

quit all other's tabs

if your's vim is not tabs you can use

```
:on
```

quit all windows